# A rectangular matrix has an inverse also?!

Tags: linear-algebra

If $A$ is a $m \times n$ matrix and $B$ is a $n \times m$ matrix, is it possible that both

$AB=I_m$

and

$BA=I_n$

where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix?

If not, is it possible to find two $n \times m$ matrices $B$ and $C$ such that

$AB=I_m$

and

$CA=I_n$

I was reading about inverse matrices from gilbert strangs book when i thought of this question, i did find a few questions about two sided inverse of a rectangular matrix, but I'm not sure if that was the same thing as what I'm referring to...

I tried to find some examples for $(m,n)=(3,2)$ but I couldn't get anywhere...

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Hint: What can you say about the ranks of $AB$ and $CA$?

Comment: Have you tried this with $m=1$ and $n=2$?

Comment: Write $A(A^T(AA^T)^{-1})$; I think you will agree this evaluates to $I_m$. What would you do for the left inverse?